# Spring JdbcTemplate with DBCP BasicDataSource still closes connections

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-jdbc

I'm using postgres jdbc driver to connect to Amazon RedShift. Here are also `BasicDataSource` from `DBCP 2.0.1` and `JdbcTemplate` from `Spring 4`. I use `DataSourceTransactionManager` with `Transactional` annotations.

It looks like `DataSource` still keeps on creating new connections!

```
    // that is how dataSource is created

BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource() {
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
         Connection c = super.getConnection();
         System.out.println("New connection: " + c);
         return c;
    }
};

dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty(USERNAME));
dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty(PASSWORD));
dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty(DRIVER_CLASS));
dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty(CONNECTION_URL));
```

and I see in console for each operation another Connection object (they have different hashcodes). If I switch to `SingleConnectionDataSource` all works as expected, with a single connection object.

Before call to  `jdbcTemplate#execute` I use `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive` to see that transactions are working (they are)...

What could I miss then? Why transactions are closed? Or what more can I do to investigate the problem. The url also have `tcpKeepAlive=true` parameter...

**UPD** thanks to Evgeniy, I've changed the code to see when connections are really created:

```
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource() {
        protected ConnectionFactory createConnectionFactory() throws SQLException {
            final ConnectionFactory cf = super.createConnectionFactory();
            return new ConnectionFactory() {
                public Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
                    Connection c = cf.createConnection();
                    System.out.println("New connection from factory: " + c);
                    return c;
                }
            };
        }
    };
    //dataSource.setMaxIdle(0);
```

Now I really see that **only two** connections were created (and if I add `setMaxIdle(0)` they are instead recreated before each query).

So my suspicion was wrong and pool works as expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No it doesn't create new connections, internally it keeps a pool of connections. The `getConnection` method is the way to get a connection in a transparent way regardless of the fact if a connection pool or basic `DriverManager` based `DataSource` implementation is used. So basically checking the `getConnection` method is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different hash codes do not prove they are different physical connections. Try to watch sessions on the database and you will see that close on connection from `BasicDataSource` does not close a physical connection.

Comment: I used a session monitor on MySQL: when I close a connection from DriverManager it is closed on DB, but closing a connection from BasicDataSource does not close DB connection

Comment: Yes, thanks - then I should try to find better way to monitor connections.

Comment: Evgeniy, thanks, you were right. I'll update the question with my new code based on your hint.